# adding json data to shared preferences more than once in flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

```
         RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            List<String> item = [
              widget.menu.iName.toString(),
              widget.menu.iId.toString(),
              widget.menu.iCount.toString()
            ];
            List<String> items = [];
            if (item != null) {
              items.addAll(item);
              pref.setStringList('products', items);
            } else {
              print("there are no items");
            }
          },
          child: Text("Add"),
        ),



         RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            List<String> myItems = await SharedPrefLib.listOfProducts();
            if (basket != null) {
              basket.forEach((f) {
                print(f);
              });
            } else {
              print("there is nothing");
            }
          },
          child: Text("show products"),
        ),
```

I would like to add more than one list of products to the shared preferences but everytime when i hit the add button it just adds one list of products and no more.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you reset `items` every time when click Raised Button 
So `items` list will not keep history `item`

```
List<String> items = [];
```

You have to move out this line out of Raised Button

code snippet

```
List<String> items = [];

RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            List<String> item = [
              widget.menu.iName.toString(),
              widget.menu.iId.toString(),
              widget.menu.iCount.toString()
            ];

            if (item != null) {
              items.addAll(item);
              pref.setStringList('products', items);
            } else {
              print("there are no items");
            }
          },
          child: Text("Add"),
        ),
```

Comment: I tried sir but still don't work as i want, it just lists the last item in the list

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p2c74KSnCw/ this is last version of the code

Comment: this line List<String> urunler = []; sitll in your class SharedPrefLib, you have to move it out out class SharedPrefLib

Comment: I did it after wrote my last comment then i realized that there was a problem bu using this code pref.setStringList('products', items); I was using it instead of using my addToChart() method. by the way thanks bro